# How do I build Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, build

I am working on a research project where I am going to analyze several of the commits in the version control history for [Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails). I would like to see which commits pass or fail Rails' test scripts. If it is possible, I would also like to see which commits can be built.

For example, if I were analyzing a Java project, I would try to compile the project at each commit. If the compilation process failed, then I would know that the commit broke the build. Then, on a successful build, I could run the test scripts.

I know that most Ruby projects do not have a build process in the same sense that Java projects do because Ruby is interpreted. So an error that a compiler could check, like a syntax error or type error, will always be found at runtime. Because of this, I'm not sure whether Rails has a build process and if it does, what that process is. **Does Rails have a build process or a process that is analogous to compiling a project in a compiled language?**

Comment: Downvoters, can you please explain yours downvotes? I believe this question is on-topic, and while I didn't say so in my question, I have read the Rail documentation before posting, which only discusses testing, not building (see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/development_dependencies_install.html and http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html). I'm wondering if there's any obscure knowledge about building that the Rails community is aware of that is hard to find.

Comment: I wasn't a downvoter, but I can tell that you would have been downvoted because the only thing analogous to compiling a project in a compiled language is to take the steps outlined in the docs you now tell us that you've read. Ie. going through the steps in [Setting Up a Development Environment](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#setting-up-a-development-environment), at that point you can fully run Rails, just like you could in a compiled language once you'd compiled the project.

Comment: @smathy I have to admit, I strongly suspect that the answer to my question is that there isn't a build process for Rails. You're right that if there was one, it would have been well-documented.

Comment: Yeah, there's no build process for setting up a development environment. There's a build process for deploying a new version of the Rails gem, but you didn't ask about a process analogous to a deploying a compiled language project, only to building one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. There are definitely some setup steps before you can run any tests.

Like all good open source projects if you scroll down on the README page at the link you included in your question, you'll see [the Contributing section](https://github.com/rails/rails#contributing). That links to everything you need to know in order to set up Rails and start either developing, or doing your test research project thing.